# document directory behaving as though empty on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, directory, document

The documents directory of my app contains sub folders and files, like so:

[image: Shot of app's Document folder]

I'm trying to retrieve the documents for display with this code:

```
NSMutableArray *documentData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];

NSString *myFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads/Diagrams"];
NSLog(@"rostering at: %@", myFolder);

NSArray *folderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myFolder error:&error];
NSLog(@"contetns of diagrams folder: %@", folderContents);
```

When I run this on the iPad, no documents are fetched for display and the output to the console is:

```
contetns of diagrams folder: (null)
```

When I run it on the simulator, the documents are displayed fine and the output is:

```
contetns of diagrams folder: (
"6901-6905.doc",
"7100-71101.doc",
"1234-5678.doc"
```

)

Is there any obvious explanation as to what might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: When `folderContents` is null, what is the error?

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks for the reply. I don't see any error in the console output.

Comment: @Robert you need to log the error like this NSLog (@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that the Simulator is not case sensitive whereas the Device is.